# Is there any way to change background color of comments in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to change the color of the comments so that it can be highlighted. I prefer to change background-color most of the time. I found the color setting in `setting.json`. it looks like this.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "comment",
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "bold",
                "foreground": "#FFD83B"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It does change but it seems like there is no "background" option in "settings". it says "Token background colors are currently not supported."
so I only can change the text color, not the background. is there any way I can set background color of comments in VSCode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any way to do that built-in.  You could look through the extensions - search for `comment` - to see if any of them do that.

Alternatively, one way to do it would be to use an extension like [highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight).  You can style anything you can capture with a regex.  In settings.json:

```
"highlight.regexes": {

 "(//\\s*)(\\sTODO\\s)(\\s*?:?)(.*)": [
   {},
   {
    "overviewRulerColor": "#ffcc00", // does this work?
    // "backgroundColor": "#aaa",
    "color": "#fff",
    "fontWeight": "bold",
    "letterSpacing": "2.5px",
    "outline": "1px solid #aaa",
    // "border": "1px solid #fff",
    // "before": {
    //   "backgroundColor": "#fff",
    //   "contentText": " *** ",
    //   "fontWeight": "bold",
    //   "margin": "10px"
    //   // "width": "20px"
    // }
   },
   {},
   {
    "color": "#999",
    "fontStyle": "italic",
    "letterSpacing": "1px"
   }
 ],

 "(//\\s*)(-+\\s+//)": [
   {
    "color": "#000",
    "backgroundColor": "#aaa",
    "outline": "2px solid #aaa",
    "fontWeight": "bold",
   },
   {
    "overviewRulerColor": "#ffcc00",
    "backgroundColor": "#aaa",
    "color": "#000",
    "fontWeight": "bold",
    // "letterSpacing": "2.5px",
    "outline": "2px solid #aaa",
    // "border": "1px solid #fff",
    // "before": {
    //   "backgroundColor": "#fff",
    //   "contentText": " *** ",
    //   "fontWeight": "bold",
    //   "margin": "10px"
    //   // "width": "20px"
    // }
   },
 ]
},
```

yields:

[image: highlight demo]

For styling options, see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions

Comment: This is something that I exactly needed! thank you so much