# VS Code change comment BACKGROUND color

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is this even possible? I do it in full-blown Visual Studio and it's very helpful. Any time you search "VS Code change text/comment background color" you just find articles on how to change the editor's background color. I want to change the background color of comments so they look like they're always highlighted and stand out.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58887379/is-there-any-way-to-change-background-color-of-comments-in-vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the extension [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight)

An example setting for C++ and JavaScript comments:

```
"highlight.regexes": {
  "(//.*)": [
    {
      "overviewRulerColor": "#ffcc00",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffcc00",
      "filterLanguageRegex": "cpp|javascript"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you also have `/* */` comments you have to add another regex that also spans line endings.